# Regular expression doesn't match a string at the end of file

Tags: regex

I have a Regexp for searching an email :

```
\b([a-z]\w{1,13}\.)?([a-z]\w{1,13})@([a-z]\w{1,13}\.){1,5}(com|de|sng|hkg|net|appl|it|lu|mc|sg|us|hk|ch)(\b|$|\z|\Z|\n)
```

It works fine with string which is not in the end of file but when i put a string with email format in the end of file, it can't detect the email. Please help to correct this regexp. Any help would be great.

There's text i tried for testing :

NX_LOCAL_HOST=@@XXXXXX@@

NX_USER=@@YYYYYYY@@

NX_SLUMP_HOST=@@NX_SLUMP_HOST@@

NX_SLUMP_NAME=2100

nhbigshow@yahoo.com

NX_MGR_PORTNUM=2300

NX_KEY=0x4E580000

NX_SERVER=@@NX_SERVER@@

@NX_JRE_INSTALL_DIR=@@NX_JRE_INSTALL_DIR_HOLA_NX@@

DKBO609 @NX_JRE_INSTALL_DIR=@@NX_JRE_INSTALL_DIR_HOLA_28@@

NX_DOMSRVR_NAME=ANY_DE

! @NX_NOFASTCHAN=Deinstalled Thu Jun 06 11:54:17 2013

NX_LOG=$NX_LOCAL/log

NX_SITE=$NX_LOCAL/site

@NX_PREFERENCE_DIR=H:\USPSD

anhbigshow@yahoo.com

C:\abc\def

anhbigshow@gmail.com

It's only match "nhbigshow@yahoo.com".

Comment: Is your file line ending configured for windows, mac or unix ?

Comment: What program are you using? What input are you using? Are you sure the regex matches the string when it's not at the end of the file?

Comment: What does your file look like?

Comment: One reason @AmalMurali aduch and  iamnotmaynard are asking you these questions is that by itself, the regex matches (see [demo](http://regex101.com/r/xH1mO5)). So these questions about your environment are important.

Comment: Do you say that first `nhbigshow@yahoo.com` is not matched?

Comment: @aduch : i'm using .txt file in window

Comment: @iamnotmaynard : it's c#. Yes. i'm sure about that

Comment: @AmalMurali : Sorry. I edited the question. It's only matched the first string

Comment: @user3663340: How are you performing the match? What language/platform are you using for this purpose?

Comment: @AmalMurali:i'm using C#. I tested this regex in http://regex101.com/r/jO6cB3
It's only matched the first case

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does .NET Regex support global matching?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715428/does-net-regex-support-global-matching)

Comment: It looks like you want a global match, which uses a different command to find a list of all matches. Also, your regex only matches lowercase letters. This might not be what you want. Try `[A-Za-z]` to catch all letters, or `\w` for all letters as well as numbers and underscore.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you gave an example of what it is matching and not matching. If you are looking to match something that must end with `X`, then the the expression is `X$`. You will most likely find your answer here: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression
I end up there myself sometimes as a refresher. It's a very detailed guide.

As a test, see if it can match just the last part. I have the feeling what you are looking for is for each item to end with `(com|de|sng|hkg|net|appl|it|lu|mc|sg|us|hk|ch)` followed by some delimiter that signifies the end of the line. Try this:

```
.*(com|de|sng|hkg|net|appl|it|lu|mc|sg|us|hk|ch)([^a-zA-Z]|$)
```

I used the question mark to show that it is optional. Brackets to show that 1 item from this set will be there. Let me know if this helps. .* means that "any character" can be there "0 or more times".

What you are looking for should be something similar to this. This is from the link in the comment.

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@
(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|
biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum)\b
```

Comment: The OP is already using `(\b|$|\z|\Z|\n)`, which [should work](http://regex101.com/r/jO6cB3). I don't think `[\b\z\Z\n]?$` is correct (or would work) because `$` can never happen after `\Z`.

Comment: Where are you using regex? Java, VB, ...? Each library is very different with lots of special features in each.

Comment: Oh, it must be Perl. Since you are looking for email addresses, check out this. http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html and RFC 5322. You can double check the email part is right. Using ([^a-zA-Z]|$) should be enough to show that the .com/.edu/.de portion of the string has ended. I would avoid using \b and \z where possible, but that is just my personal preference to avoid unintended functionality.

Comment: I'm using c#. It's only matched the first case.

Comment: Without testing this myself, then next thing is to try modifying your example and see if you can make "nhbigshow@yahoo.com" stop matching and "anhbigshow@gmail.com" to start matching. You might figure out where the problem is. There may be a Unicode character there that you can't see or something else wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using python. If that is the case, your `regex` will work with `findall`

```
>>> string
'NX_LOCAL_HOST=@@XXXXXX@@ \nNX_USER=@@YYYYYYY@@ \nNX_SLUMP_HOST=@@NX_SLUMP_HOST@@        \nNX_SLUMP_NAME=2100 \nnhbigshow@yahoo.com \nNX_MGR_PORTNUM=2300 \nNX_KEY=0x4E580000 \nNX_SERVER=@@NX_SERVER@@ \n@NX_JRE_INSTALL_DIR=@@NX_JRE_INSTALL_DIR_HOLA_NX@@\n\n\nDKBO609 @NX_JRE_INSTALL_DIR=@@NX_JRE_INSTALL_DIR_HOLA_28@@\n\n\nNX_DOMSRVR_NAME=ANY_DE \n! @NX_NOFASTCHAN=Deinstalled Thu Jun 06 11:54:17 2013 \nNX_LOG=$NX_LOCAL/log \nNX_SITE=$NX_LOCAL/site \n@NX_PREFERENCE_DIR=H:\\USPSD \nanhbigshow@yahoo.com \nC:\x07bc\\def \nanhbigshow@gmail.com'
>>> regex = re.findall(r"\b([a-z]\w{1,13}\.)?([a-z]\w{1,13})@([a-z]\w{1,13}\.){1,5}(com|de|sng|hkg|net|appl|it|lu|mc|sg|us|hk|ch)(\b|$|\z|\Z|\n)",s)
>>> regex
[('', 'nhbigshow', 'yahoo.', 'com', ''), ('', 'anhbigshow', 'yahoo.', 'com', ''), ('', 'anhbigshow', 'gmail.', 'com', '')]
```

Comment: i'm using C#. Can you explain it in c# ? it's only matched the first case

Comment: I don't know `C#`. There must be some way to search all occurrences in `C#` too.